# How can i change 'selection cursor' color in Android?

Tags: android

[How to change color of this black 'droplet?'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ipFz.png)

It changes with the accentColor, but I need another way to change the color.

Comment: Do you want to change the cursor color as well?

Comment: did you find any solution ?